# Receiving duplicate msg in the consumer

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafkajs

`Issue:` Our consumer service is receiving duplicate msg even after placing a commit on the offset.

`Tried:` Initially we had the interval level commit and then moved to the offset level commit but still this didn't solve the issue. I am also simulating CICD(restarting services every 2 minutes) because we mostly encounter duplication when there is a pod restart or there is a deployment happening.

`Current Setup:`

PFB the methods we have:

initialize consumer

```
const groupId = `group-${topicName.toLowerCase()}-${process.env.NODE_ENV}`;
```

we have a bunch of services having the same groupID

subscribeConsumer

```
await this.consumer.subscribe({
     topic,
     fromBeginning: true,
});
```

getMessage

```
this.consumer.run({
    eachBatchAutoResolve: false,
    // autoCommitInterval: 1000,
    // autoCommitThreshold: 5,
    eachBatch: async ({ batch, resolveOffset, heartbeat, isRunning, isStale }) => {
                if (!isRunning() || isStale()) return;
                await heartbeat();
                await processTopicMsg(logger, batch.messages, country, resolveOffset, heartbeat);
                await heartbeat();
            },
        });
```

`processTopicMsg:`

perform the processing of the msg

```
resolveOffset(topicMsg[Index].offset);
await heartbeat();
```

Comment: "we mostly encounter duplication when there is a pod restart or there is a deployment happening" - are your pods exiting cleanly? Sounds like maybe the message starts getting processed, but the pod terminates without managing to commit. You could try commiting first, and then processing the message in your code after you've resolved it in kafka, however, if the code throws, that'd kinda suck. It would rule out what the problem is, though.

Comment: When killing pods, the SIGKILL signal will be sent to the running process. Maybe handling SIGKILL in your code would be enough to fix this issue.

Comment: "You could try commiting first, and then processing", @LeonardoG Chances of message loss is high here, we can't afford losing any msg.  As those are txn messages.

Comment: I understand, but you could try it as a diagnostic measure in a different environment just to verify if that's the issue. You can also try logging every step of execution to see if it really exits mid-execution and fails to commit.

Comment: Kafka doesn't guarantee exactly once processing in a consumer, only exactly once *delivery* from a producer (with txn enabled). There is a difference. You should try to write idempotent processing code

Comment: @LeonardoG SIGKILL gives out errors and seems it can't be handled.

Comment: The SIGKILL signal is sent to a process to cause it to terminate immediately (kill). In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, this signal cannot be caught or ignored, and the receiving process cannot perform any clean-up upon receiving this signal.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I switched them up. Assuming you are using Kubernetes, a SIGTERM (which can be handled) will be sent to your process, not SIGKILL. If the process does not exit after the grace period then SIGKILL will be sent. Anyway, we are still not even sure if process termination is your issue, so you have some diagnosing to do.

Comment: @LeonardoGazdek I can get the msg handler log for "SIGTERM". How can i stop the consumer from reading? shall I pause it ?